# Installing mlr package in AzureML Experiment

Tags: r, azure, mlr

I am trying to install mlr package in AzureML Experiment, but getting Error, I have the windows binary zip file for the mlr package and its dependencies like ParamHelpers, and connected the zip in a module to Execute R Script, I am getting the following Errors.

```
install.packages("src/ParamHelpers_1.12.zip",lib=".",repos=NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(ParamHelpers,lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)

install.packages("src/mlr_2.13.zip",lib=".",repos=NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(mlr,lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
library(mlr)
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)
ncol(dataset1)
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1");
```

```
Status code
Failed
Status details
requestId = 5541aec465e74f3d83b28273a6433ce2 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. 
{"Exception":"ErrorId":"FailedToEvaluateRScript","ErrorCode":"0063",
"ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 0063: 
The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:\r\n---------- 
Start of error message from R ----------\r\nthere is no package 
called 'ParamHelpers'\r\n\r\n\r\nthere is no package 
called 'ParamHelpers'\r\n----------- End of error message from R 
-----------"}}
Error: Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------there is no package
 called 'ParamHelpers'there is no package called 
'ParamHelpers'----------- End of error message from R ----------- 
Process exited with error code -2
```

Looking forward to execute mlr package successfully in AzureML

Comment: The Path having an issue, I tried
"./src/ParamHelpers_1.12.zip"
"/src/ParamHelpers_1.12.zip"
"src/ParamHelpers_1.12.zip"

Nothing Working

Answer (score 1):

I see you tried to follow the section [`Importing packages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/extend-your-experiment-with-r#importing-packages) of the offical tutorial `Azure Machine Learning Studio: Extend your experiment with R` to  install your required library `ParamHelpers` and failed.

As I known, the simple way to install a package unincluded in Azure ML is to package it as a zip file and to upload it as a dataset, then you can drag it from `My datasets` of `Saved Datasets` in the left toolbar, for example I want to use `curl` library, as the figure below.

[image]

And the code in `Execute R Script` is the sample code of `curl` as below, and it works fine like running in my local RStudio.

The `curl` sample code ran on my local RStudio
[image]

The same code works fine on Azure ML
[image]

I just upload the `curl_3.3.zip` file from the downloaded packages directory (like C:\Users\peterp\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp82CVoW\downloaded_packages) of my RStudio to Azure as a dataset, as the figures below.

Fig 1. To click the `+ NEW` button
[image]

Fig 2. Select the `DATASETS`-> `FROM LOCAL FILE`
[image]

Fig 3. Choose a zip file and upload
[image]

Then, you can see it in the left toolbar.

If you want to install more packages, you just need to decompress them and compress their directories to a zip file again and upload it.

[image]

The custom package zip file `my-required-libs.zip` also works fine.

[image]

Hope it helps.